# Trying to set the Chrome download directory for Python Seleniumbase but it continues to use the default

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, seleniumbase

I'm still learning how to use Selenium Python and am having an issue changing the default download directory. I'm hoping a fresh or more experienced set of eyes can help.

I'm rocking with Python 3.10.11 / Selenium 4.10 / Chrome (whatever latest version is)

Below is the relevant code -- the entire script runs with no errors, but instead of using the directory path I supply it'll just create a subfolder called "downloaded_files" from whatever directory the script is running from and dump the files there.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from seleniumbase import Driver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

download_path = "\\\E275proddwdb\kyote"

# Set download folder
op = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
config = {"download.default_directory":download_path, "safebrowsing.enabled":"false"}
op.add_experimental_option("prefs", config)
op.headless = False

##Call Chrome Browser
service = Service()
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
browser = Driver(browser="chrome", headless=False) 
browser.get("https://www.kyote.org/mc/login.aspx?url=kplacementMgmt.aspx")
```

Any help in figuring out how I messed this up would be greatly, greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing two separate frameworks into one. You have `webdriver` with those `options`, and you have `seleniumbase`, which is configured differently. The `downloaded_files` folder is hard-coded in `constants` ([seleniumbase/fixtures/constants.py](https://github.com/seleniumbase/SeleniumBase/blob/eea244127cf26daac6ec28a3139382378071e0d5/seleniumbase/fixtures/constants.py#L79)), and for good reason. That folder is uniquely-named so that files downloaded to that folder don't get mixed up with anything else outside `seleniumbase`.

Here's a working script for the latest version of `seleniumbase` (`4.19.0`):

```py
from seleniumbase import Driver

driver = Driver(browser="chrome", headless=False)
try:
    driver.get("https://www.kyote.org/mc/login.aspx?url=kplacementMgmt.aspx")
    driver.type('input[id*="UserName"]', "MyName")
    driver.type('input[id*="Password"]', "PASSWORD")
    driver.sleep(2)
    driver.click('[value="Log In"]')
    driver.sleep(4)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

The new direct `driver` methods such as `click()` and `type()` were added only this week (in `4.18.9`), so you'll definitely want to make sure you have the latest version or the one immediately preceding that.

Comment: You have helped me before and you are truly my spirit animal :). I'm marking this as the correct answer because it works and you explained that you cannot change the download path in SeleniumBase. I think what's happened is somewhere along the lines I've gotten selenium Manager and SeleniumBase confused and thought they were one in the same. What I really need is to focus on getting Selenium Manager to work, but if I run into any issues I'll open a new post for that.  Again, thanks!